# Active Directory authentication for Umbraco 7.6 gets stuck in a re-direct loop

Tags: azure, authentication, active-directory, owin, umbraco

I am currently using an Umbraco library to extend the Authentication possibilities and enable back office authentication with Active Directory.

https://github.com/umbraco/UmbracoIdentityExtensions

After installing the library and following the blog post below, I was able to display an external login button, authenticate with Active Directory and add a user and external login to the Umbraco database.

https://www.jdibble.co.uk/blog/securing-umbraco-backoffice-with-azure-active-directory/

This then sends you back to the /umbraco login page in a continuous loop. As described by this blog post https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/75256-login-uisng-azure-ad-redirects-allways-to-login-page

Has anyone faced this issue and solved it? Or have any useful suggestions?

The code being used...

```
   public static void ConfigureBackOfficeAzureActiveDirectoryAuth(this IAppBuilder app,
          string tenant, string clientId, string postLoginRedirectUri, Guid issuerId,
          string caption = "Active Directory", string style = "btn-microsoft", string icon = "fa-windows")
    {
        var authority = string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}",
            tenant);

        var adOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = Constants.Security.BackOfficeExternalAuthenticationType,
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            RedirectUri = postLoginRedirectUri,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
                {
                    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

                    var userService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.UserService;

                    var stuff = (List<Claim>)context.JwtSecurityToken.Claims;

                    var email = stuff.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "unique_name").Value;
                    var issuer = stuff.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "iss").Value;
                    var providerKey = stuff.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "sub").Value;
                    var name = stuff.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "name").Value;

                    var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<BackOfficeUserManager>();

                    var user = userService.GetByEmail(email);

                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        var writerUserType = userService.GetUserTypeByName("writer");
                        user = userService.CreateUserWithIdentity(email, email, writerUserType);
                    }

                    var identity = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
                    if (identity.Logins.All(x => x.ProviderKey != providerKey))
                    {
                        identity.Logins.Add(new IdentityUserLogin(issuer, providerKey, user.Id));
                        identity.Name = name;

                        var result = userManager.Update(identity);
                    }
                },
            }
        };

        adOptions.ForUmbracoBackOffice(style, icon);
        adOptions.Caption = caption;

        //Need to set the auth type as the issuer path
        adOptions.AuthenticationType = string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "https://sts.windows.net/{0}/",
            issuerId);

        adOptions.SetExternalSignInAutoLinkOptions(new ExternalSignInAutoLinkOptions(autoLinkExternalAccount: true));

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(adOptions);
    }
```

Comment: Did you get any error message? You can capture the request using Fiddler to check it.

Comment: No errors through Fiddler appeared. We had already tried that but not a bad suggestion. I have no fixed this issue by creating a fresh project and installing all the components from scratch. Same code though...

Comment: Update: The problem is with using Redis Cache.

Comment: Have you fix the issue? If not would you mind sharing the code about how to use the Redis cache and the root cause?

Comment: At this stage the root cause is unknown other than using redis causes it. So removing/commenting out </sessionState> section referring to redis in the web.config to allow Umbraco to use its default has enabled the azure active directory login to function properly. Once/If a fix is found for this, I'll post it as an answer here.

Comment: Stumbled across this after hours of trial and error. Code was almost identical but think they key change of authority from `https://login.windows.net/{0}` to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}` did it. I also noticed you were using `userManager.Update()` which may have helped too.... THANK YOU!

Comment: Excellent! Glad this helped someone :)

Comment: I've noticed that the Sign in with AD stops working periodically (a recycle gets it working again). Have you seen that at all? @JessonAtherton

Comment: @swiss196 this also is the issue for me. Restarting the site fixes the issue. That's why this is difficult to debug, I can't really reproduce it locally.

Comment: No I have not, sorry. There could be more issues with different versions of Umbraco. My issue was when I used Redis Cache the azure AD login would not work. I hope you find a solution :)